# Get namespace of an XML tag using XPath

Tags: java, xml, spring-boot, xpath, apache-camel

I am having an XML like the below:

```
<RootNode xmlns="ns1">
    <Node xmlns="ns2">
        <id>TestID</id>
    </Node>
</RootNode>
```

I want to find the namespace of the element with name Node which is ns2. Can anyone please guide me how to do this using XPath? I am using Spring Boot and Apache Camel in my project.

Comment: No It is slightly different. In the example given, the root element and subsequent elements does not have a namespace, but here I will have to find the namespace of an element

Comment: @Anirban how is that different? Isn't the namespace just an attribute?